# push new object to array, the last object overwrite the whole array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to push some object inside a loop, the first three is ok but when it want to push the last one, the whole array will overwrite by the last object!

let's say I have this code, in my tasks, I have 4 items which 3 of them have `"type1"` type, and only one of them have `"type2"` , basically the second if only trigger once, but for some reason, at the end `myArray` fill with the last push! :

```
var myArray = [];
for(var i = tasks.length-1; i>=0; i--){
   if (tasks[i].type == 'type1') {
     myObject.type= 'audio',
     myObject.command = audioArgs;
     myArray.push(myObject);
   } 
   if (tasks[i].type == 'type2') {
     console.log("Before push type2: ", myArray) // Here I will get the currect value
     myObject.type= 'video',
     myObject.command = videoArgs;
     myArray.push(myObject);
     console.log("After push type2 : ", myArray) // Here all old value which have type1 will overwrite with type2
   }
}
```

and I define the `myObject` as :

```
var myObject = {
  type : String,
  command : String
}
```

Comment: All your objects in the array are having same reference. Create a new object and then push it in array. In the second condition, you are initializing `myobject` and then pushing `ffmpegCommand`

Comment: What is `ffmpegCommand`, Do you mean to push `myObject` instead there in the 2nd `if` condition?

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla That one is my project variable forgot to rename it here , I just edit it, it's the same myObject

Comment: @HassanImam the ffmpegCommand was mistype, actually I push myObject

Comment: Similarly do you also want to compare `tasks[i]` in the 2nd `if` statement, you seem to be comparing `streamsInfo[i]` instead. It'd be nice to have the sample contents of these two objects so that we could help you out.

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla yes, So sorry for that, it's same I already edit it

Comment: The reason why this is happening is because you're using the same global variable and pushing it to the array which updates the array. This doesn't even have to enter the 2nd loop and in fact changes all items even while in the first loop. The easiest solution would be to make the `var myObject` a local variable inside the `for` loop and you'll be able to get the output you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include this part inside your for loop

```
var myObject = {
  type : String,
  command : String
}
```

To make sure you are initialising a new object on every iteration. Otherwise you will be overriding the same object and pushing multiple times, and you will end up with an array with several references to a single object

Comment: Thank you. I was define this a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `myObject` inside both the if blocks. Currently in your code, you are pushing the same reference twice, so updating data via any reference updates the other. The correct code will be:

```
var myArray = [];
for (var i = tasks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (tasks[i].type == 'type1') {
        let myObject = {
            type: 'audio',
            command: audioArgs
        }; //HERE
        myArray.push(myObject);
    }
    if (tasks[i].type == 'type2') {
        console.log("Before push type2: ", myArray);
        let myObject = {
            type: 'video',
            command: videoArgs
        }; //HERE

        myArray.push(myObject);
        console.log("After push type2 : ", myArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you are using the same reference for all of your objects that you're pushing into the array. So what happens in this case is that your array contains the item pushed at every `n`th iteration. i.e. 1st push contains the 1st item. 2nd item contains 2 items both of which are the 2nd item that has been pushed into the array. Therefore you need a local scope.

```
var myArray = [];
for(var i = tasks.length-1; i>=0; i--){
   var myObject = {
     type : String,
     command : String
   }
   if (tasks[i].type == 'type1') {
     myObject.type= 'audio',
     myObject.command = audioArgs;
     myArray.push(myObject);
   } 
   if (tasks[i].type == 'type2') {
     console.log("Before push type2: ", myArray) // Here I will get the currect value
     myObject.type= 'video',
     myObject.command = videoArgs;
     myArray.push(myObject);
     console.log("After push type2 : ", myArray) // Here all old value which have type1 will overwrite with type2
   }
}
```